# fastapi bug with annotated default value

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I have this small FastAPI (fastapi==0.95.0 and uvicorn==0.20.0 in my requirements.txt) application that works as expected.

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    q: Annotated[str, Query(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")] = "a"


@app.get("/test")
def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I now restructure it to

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query, APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    q: Annotated[str, Query(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")] = "a"


def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


router = APIRouter()

router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["GET"],
)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I see this error

```
AssertionError: `Query` default value cannot be set in `Annotated` for 'q'. Set the default value with `=` instead.
```

if I remove the default value from the q field it works as expected. But when the default value (`"a"`) is added, I see the error while in the first structure, I did not have such a limitation.

Is this a bug with fast API? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug that is fixed in version 0.95.1
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9279#discussioncomment-5431795